# How to transform a matrix into a diagonal matrix by Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I want to diagonalize a matrix by orthogonalization, but the following method cannot get the correct result:

```
A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}};
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]
Eigensystem[A]
Q = Orthogonalize@(Eigensystem[A][[2]])

Transpose[Q].DiagonalMatrix[{6, 2, 2}].Q == A
Transpose[Q].A.Q == DiagonalMatrix[{6, 2, 2}]
```

I think it is probably caused by the difference between function `Orthogonalize` (`Q = Orthogonalize@(Eigensystem[A][[2]])`) and Schmidt orthogonalization.

**How can I use built-in functions to do Schmidt orthogonalization and diagonalize the matrix?**

Oddly enough, the following code returns an empty set, whereas `DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]==True` indicates that the matrix can be diagonalized:

```
Q = Array[x, {3, 3}];
A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}};
FindInstance[
 Q\[Transpose].A.Q == DiagonalMatrix[{6, 2, 2}] && 
  Q\[Transpose].Q == IdentityMatrix[3], Flatten[Q]]
```

I hope to find the orthogonal matrix `Q` by Schmidt orthogonalization and diagonalize the matrix `A`.

**The definition of Schmidt orthogonalization:**

$$\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{b}_{1}=\boldsymbol{a}_{1} \\
\boldsymbol{b}_{2}=\boldsymbol{a}_{2}-\frac{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{a}_{2}\right]}{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{b}_{1}\right]} \boldsymbol{b}_{1} \\
\cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots \\
\boldsymbol{b}_{r}=\boldsymbol{a}_{r}-\frac{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{a}_{r}\right]}{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{b}_{1}\right]} \boldsymbol{b}_{1}-\frac{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{2}, \boldsymbol{a}_{r}\right]}{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{2}, \boldsymbol{b}_{2}\right]} \boldsymbol{b}_{2}-\cdots-\frac{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{r-1}, \boldsymbol{a}_{r}\right]}{\left[\boldsymbol{b}_{r-1}, \boldsymbol{b}_{r-1}\right]} \boldsymbol{b}_{r-1},
\end{array}$$

$$\boldsymbol{e}_{1}=\frac{1}{\left\|\boldsymbol{b}_{1}\right\|} \boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \quad \boldsymbol{e}_{2}=\frac{1}{\left\|\boldsymbol{b}_{2}\right\|} \boldsymbol{b}_{2}, \quad \cdots, \quad \boldsymbol{e}_{r}=\frac{1}{\left\|\boldsymbol{b}_{r}\right\|} \boldsymbol{b}_{r}$$

$[x,y]$ is the inner product of vectors `x` and `y`.

**Other examples for testing:**

```
A = {{-2, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {-4, 1, 3}};
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]
Q = (Eigenvectors[A])
Inverse[Q].A.Q
A.Q
```

I don't know why finding eigenvector matrix does not satisfy $\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{p}_{i}=\lambda_{i} \boldsymbol{p}_{i} \quad(i=1,2, \cdots, n)$ or $Q^{-1} A Q=\Lambda$.

The eigenvector matrix $\boldsymbol{Q}=\left(\boldsymbol{p}_{1}, \boldsymbol{p}_{2}, \boldsymbol{p}_{3}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 4
\end{array}\right)$ obtained in the textbook can satisfy $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 4
\end{array}\right)^{-1} \cdot A \cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 4
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: The result of `SchurDecomposition[N[{{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}}]]` tells me that your desire to have orthonormal eigenvectors is not reasonable.

Comment: Schmidt orthogonalization is done in Mathematica with the function `QRDecomposition`.

Comment: `Orthogonalize` by default generates a Gram\[Dash]Schmidt basis.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much. I've learned that `DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]==True` indicates that `A` can be diagonalized, but `SchurDecomposition[N[{{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}}]]` means that `A` cannot be orthogonal diagonalized.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that these matrices are not symmetric matrices. In addition, eigenvector matrices need to be transposed before been used:

```
A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}};
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]
Eigensystem[A]
Q = (Eigensystem[A][[2]])
(*but this matrix is not symmetric,so Transpose is not sufficient*)
Inverse[Q\[Transpose]].A.Q\[Transpose]


A = {{-2, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {-4, 1, 3}};
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]
Q = (Eigenvectors[A])
Inverse[Q\[Transpose]].A.Q\[Transpose]

GramSchmidtOrthogonalize[mat_] := 
   Module[{matT = Transpose[mat], 
       n = Length[Transpose[mat]]}, 
     a = matT; b[1] = a[[1]]; b[i_] := 
        a[[i]] - Sum[(b[j] . a[[i]]/b[j] . b[j])*b[j], 
            {j, 1, i - 1}]; Transpose[Table[b[i], 
          {i, 1, n}]]]
GramSchmidtOrthogonalize[{{2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, 
     {0, 0, -1}}]
```

I've learned that `DiagonalizableMatrixQ[A]==True` indicates that `A` can be diagonalized, but `SchurDecomposition[N[{{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, -2, 5}}]]` means that `A` cannot be orthogonal diagonalized:

```
A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, a, 5}} /. a -> -2 ;
Q = Join[{Eigensystem[A][[2]][[1]]}\[Transpose], 
  GramSchmidtOrthogonalize[(Eigensystem[A][[2]][[2 ;; 
        All]])\[Transpose]], 2]
Inverse[Q].A.Q

GramSchmidtOrthogonalize[mat_] := 
 Module[{matT = Transpose[mat], n = Length[Transpose[mat]], a, b}, 
     a = matT; b[1] = a[[1]]; 
  b[i_] := a[[i]] - 
    Sum[(b[j] . a[[i]]/b[j] . b[j])*b[j], {j, 1, i - 1}]; 
      Transpose[Table[b[i], {i, 1, n}]]]
A = {{1, 2, -3}, {-1, 4, -3}, {1, a, 5}} /. a -> -2; 
Q = GramSchmidtOrthogonalize[Eigensystem[A][[2]]]; Normalize /@ 
 Transpose[Q]
Orthogonalize[Transpose[Eigenvectors[A]]]
```

Comment: To put it another way, your matrix is diagonalizable, but not *[normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)*.